# How do I copy variously named files with the same extension to all have a standard file name?

Tags: find, cp

I have variously named files such as in different subdirectories e.g.:

```
a/apple.txt
b/orange.txt
c/pear.txt
```

How do I copy them to have a uniform name (fruit.txt) in their respective directories so the end result is:

```
a/apple.txt
a/fruit.txt
b/orange.txt
b/fruit.txt
c/pear.txt
c/fruit.txt
```

(the contents of the file a/apple.txt and a/fruit.txt should be identical)

My thought was to do:

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} fruit.txt \;`

But I'm not sure if that would put fruit.txt in each of the respective subdirectories or if it would just put it in the current directory.

Comment: Have you tried it, perhaps in another temp directory? What are the conclusions?

Comment: you can always do `find . -name "*.txt" -exec echo cp {} fruit.txt \;` for dry run to see what is happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command,

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} fruit.txt \;
```

would correctly find all files (and directories etc.) that have a `.txt` filename suffix, in or below the current directory, and would copy them all, one after the other, to the name `fruit.txt` in the *current* directory.

What you want to do is to copy them to the same directory as the original file, and possibly to consider only *regular* files, while also avoiding any already existing `fruit.txt` name:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name fruit.txt -execdir cp -- {} fruit.txt \;
```

When you use the non-standard (but commonly available) `-execdir` predicate, the command that you use will be executed inside the directory of the found file.  This means that the above `cp` would copy the file to `fruit.txt` in the same directory as the found file.

Depending on the effect you want, you may possibly want to use a symbolic link instead of a copy of the file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name fruit.txt -execdir ln -sf -- {} fruit.txt \;
```

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas (answer editor) can you explain what the `--` does? I didn't find that I needed it.

Comment: @User, see [Where is the \`--\` (double dash) argument documented?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/570729) or [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376). Here, it would be needed with some implementations of `find` (like that of most BSDs where `-execdir` comes from) for that command to still work if there are filenames that start with `-`.